# Concatenate values based on multiple criteria

Tags: excel, concatenation

I have the following dataset

```
Key ID  Status 1    Status 2    Order ID
1   A1  FALSE        TRUE     1234-USF-0025
1   A1  FALSE        TRUE     1234-USF-0026
1   A1  FALSE        TRUE     1234-USF-0027
2   A1  TRUE         TRUE     1234-USF-0025
2   A1  TRUE         TRUE     1234-USF-0026
2   A1  TRUE         TRUE     1234-USF-0027
3   A1  FALSE        TRUE     1234-USF-0025
3   A1  FALSE        TRUE     1234-USF-0026
3   A1  FALSE        TRUE     1234-USF-0027
4   A2  TRUE         TRUE     1234-USF-0028
4   A2  TRUE         TRUE     1234-USF-0029
4   A2  TRUE         TRUE     1234-USF-0030
5   A3  TRUE         TRUE     1234-USF-0031
5   A3  TRUE         TRUE     1234-USF-0032
5   A3  TRUE         TRUE     1234-USF-0033
6   A4  TRUE         TRUE     1234-USF-0034
6   A4  TRUE         TRUE     1234-USF-0035
6   A4  TRUE         TRUE     1234-USF-0036
```

I need the following

```
Order ID        ID  TRUE    FALSE
1234-USF-0025   A1   2       1,3
1234-USF-0026   A1   2       1,3
1234-USF-0027   A1   2       1,3
1234-USF-0028   A2   4  
1234-USF-0029   A2   4  
1234-USF-0030   A2   4  
1234-USF-0031   A3   5  
1234-USF-0032   A3   5  
1234-USF-0033   A3   5  
1234-USF-0034   A4   6  
1234-USF-0035   A4   6  
1234-USF-0036   A4   6
```

In the second table (the one I need), each `Order ID` is listed next to the corresponding `ID`. Although  `A1` is listed 9 times in the original dataset, there are only 3 unique `Order IDs` in total for `A1`. However, `A1` is also associated with 3 different Keys.

The goal is to concatenate the `Keys` for each `Order ID` and `ID` combination, where both `Status 1` and `Status 2` are `TRUE` and list them in the `TRUE` column. For those `Order ID` and `ID` combinations where at least one `Status` is `FALSE`, the `Keys` should be listed under the `FALSE` column.

**What I've tried**

1. I tried starting with just the `TRUE` column, using INDEX-MATCH as an array formula, and although I know the below formula would not work for my desired end goal, I was trying to start small and build upon the formula. Unfortunately, my knowledge of arrays is limited, I'm not sure how to proceed because I don't understand why it returns what it does or how to reach my goal from this point.

`=INDEX($C$2:$C$19,MATCH(1,($H2 = $B$2:$B$19) * ($G2 = $E$2:$E$19)))`

[image]

2. Next I tried to break the pieces apart in the original dataset, but got stuck on how to proceed. I think this is the easier solution, but I can't figure out how to concatenate based on the required criteria.

TRUE: `=IF(AND($C2=TRUE,$D2=TRUE),$A2,"")`

FALSE: `=IF(OR($C2<>TRUE,$D2<>TRUE),$A2,"")`
[image]

**Notes:**

- An `ID` is associated with at least one `Key`, but can have more
- `Order ID` can repeat for the same `ID` but only for different `Keys` for that `ID`.

I am open to a `VBA`, `Python` or `R` based solution as well, but not sure how to even start a script for this task, so I've been focusing on `Excel`.

Comment: Is the first column from the second table already "built" in this scenario? Or do you need to create it from scratch based on the first table every time?

Comment: @BYates, my solution for that is to concatenate the `Order ID` with the `ID` in another tab, remove duplicates and strip out the `Order ID` to paste in the second table. However, if anyone can help with a better solution, I'm open.

Comment: This would be tricky to pull off with formulas, but if you're open to a VBA solution I could probably assist...

Comment: @BYates, VBA would work just fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kinda a verbose solution and assumes your data is exactly as you posted (and also on sheet1), but it works (I think). You'll also need to create a second sheet for the output data. Let me know if you're not sure where to post this code/how to run it.

```
Sub DoStuff()
    'Initialize the output sheet
    Sheet2.Cells.Clear
    Sheet2.Cells(1, 1) = "Order ID"
    Sheet2.Cells(1, 2) = "ID"
    Sheet2.Cells(1, 3) = "TRUE"
    Sheet2.Cells(1, 4) = "FALSE"
    newRow = 2

    'Loop through the first sheet and remove duplicates
    lastRow = Sheet1.Range("E:E").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        exists = False
        For j = 2 To newRow
            If Sheet1.Cells(i, 5).Value = Sheet2.Cells(j, 1).Value Then
                exists = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If exists = False Then
            Sheet2.Cells(newRow, 1) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 5).Value
            Sheet2.Cells(newRow, 2) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value
            'Populate the true and false columns
            For k = 2 To lastRow
                If Sheet1.Cells(k, 5).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 5).Value Then
                    If Sheet1.Cells(k, 3).Value = True And Sheet1.Cells(k, 4).Value = True Then
                        Sheet2.Cells(newRow, 3) = Sheet2.Cells(newRow, 3).Value & Sheet1.Cells(k, 1).Value & ", "
                    Else
                        Sheet2.Cells(newRow, 4) = Sheet2.Cells(newRow, 4).Value & Sheet1.Cells(k, 1).Value & ", "
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            'Remove extra characters, if there are any
            If Sheet2.Cells(newRow, 3).Value <> "" Then
                Sheet2.Cells(newRow, 3).Value = Left(Sheet2.Cells(newRow, 3).Value, Len(Sheet2.Cells(newRow, 3).Value) - 2)
            End If
            If Sheet2.Cells(newRow, 4).Value <> "" Then
                Sheet2.Cells(newRow, 4).Value = Left(Sheet2.Cells(newRow, 4).Value, Len(Sheet2.Cells(newRow, 4).Value) - 2)
            End If
            newRow = newRow + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Results using your data as posted:

[image]

Comment: thanks! I do have a couple quick questions if you don't mind. I'll be in `MS Excel` chat.

Comment: I'm not sure what that is...would you be able to ask your questions in this thread via comments?

Comment: I tend to use SO at work, and my company blocks chat rooms (including that one you provided the link for), so I cannot partake.

Comment: No worries, I just wanted to understand the code better, but everything is working for me. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I used a dictionary and a Class module to help gather and transform the data.
It also has the advantage of being a bit easier to follow and maintain since the named parameters are more or less obvious.

I also "did the work" in a VBA array as, with any sizeable database, the execution speed will be considerably faster.

It should be obvious within the code where to define the worksheets and ranges you want to use for your source data and results

### Regular Module

---

```
Option Explicit
'Set reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Sub orgOrders()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim dOrds As Dictionary, cOrd As cOrder
    Dim I As Long, V As Variant
    Dim sKey As String

'set source and result worksheet and range
Set wsSrc = Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set wsRes = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 10)

'read source data into array
With wsSrc
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp))
End With

'Read into order dictionary
Set dOrds = New Dictionary
For I = 2 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    Set cOrd = New cOrder
    sKey = vSrc(I, 5) 'Order ID
    With cOrd
        .ID = vSrc(I, 2)
        .Key = vSrc(I, 1)
        .Status1 = vSrc(I, 3)
        .Status2 = vSrc(I, 4)
        .addTrueFalse .Key, .Status1, .Status2

    If Not dOrds.Exists(sKey) Then
        dOrds.Add Key:=sKey, Item:=cOrd
    Else
        dOrds(sKey).addTrueFalse .Key, .Status1, .Status2
    End If

    End With
Next I

'Dim Results array
ReDim vRes(0 To dOrds.Count, 1 To 4)

'Headers
    vRes(0, 1) = "Order ID"
    vRes(0, 2) = "ID"
    vRes(0, 3) = "TRUE"
    vRes(0, 4) = "FALSE"

'Data
I = 0
For Each V In dOrds.Keys
    I = I + 1
    With dOrds(V)
        vRes(I, 1) = V
        vRes(I, 2) = .ID
        vRes(I, 3) = .TrueFalse(True)
        vRes(I, 4) = .TrueFalse(False)
    End With
Next V

'Write results
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    .Rows(1).Font.Bold = True
    With .EntireColumn
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .AutoFit
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

### Class Module

***RENAME this module cOrder***

---

```
Option Explicit
Private pKey As Long
Private pID As String
Private pStatus1 As Boolean
Private pStatus2 As Boolean
Private pTrueFalse As Dictionary

Public Property Get Key() As Long
    Key = pKey
End Property
Public Property Let Key(Value As Long)
    pKey = Value
End Property

Public Property Get ID() As String
    ID = pID
End Property
Public Property Let ID(Value As String)
    pID = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Status1() As Boolean
    Status1 = pStatus1
End Property
Public Property Let Status1(Value As Boolean)
    pStatus1 = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Status2() As Boolean
    Status2 = pStatus2
End Property
Public Property Let Status2(Value As Boolean)
    pStatus2 = Value
End Property

Public Function addTrueFalse(Key As Long, Status1 As Boolean, Status2 As Boolean)
        If Status1 = True And Status2 = True Then
            If Not pTrueFalse.Exists(True) Then
                pTrueFalse.Add Key:=True, Item:=Key
            Else
                pTrueFalse(True) = pTrueFalse(True) & "," & Key
            End If
        Else
            If Not pTrueFalse.Exists(False) Then
                pTrueFalse.Add Key:=False, Item:=Key
            Else
                pTrueFalse(False) = pTrueFalse(False) & "," & Key
            End If
        End If
End Function

Public Property Get TrueFalse() As Dictionary
   Set TrueFalse = pTrueFalse
End Property


Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pTrueFalse = New Dictionary
End Sub
```